# Использование CPU Android

Tags: android, cpu

Можем ли мы получить процент от используемых ресурсов CPU конкретного приложения или нескольких приложений? Данная функция часто практикуется в таскиллерах и диспетчерах задач.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте профайлер [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) который идет в поставке Android SDK.